# Get Unicode filenames on robocopy log from powershell

Tags: powershell, unicode, encoding, utf-8, robocopy

I am trying to create a log file from robocopy that I use in a script to sync two folders.
The folders contain filenames with greek characters.
In my workstation that the def codepage is Greek both the following commands create a readable log file:

```
ROBOCOPY \\app-srv\D\DocumentFiles\2012\10\8\ \\hyper-v9\W\DocumentFiles\2012\10\8\ /IA:AO /FP /NP /E /L /V /TEE /UNILOG:myfiles.txt
ROBOCOPY \\app-srv\D\DocumentFiles\2012\10\8\ \\hyper-v9\W\DocumentFiles\2012\10\8\ /IA:AO /FP /NP /E /L /V | Tee-Object myfiles.txt
```

On the server (US-EN codepage) that I want to run this I get "??" or chinese characters or control characters (with various tests..)

I had tried `/LOG:myfiles.txt, /UNICODE /LOG:myfiles.txt, /UNICODE /UNILOG:myfiles.txt, | Out-File myfiles.txt -Encoding utf8, | Out-File myfiles.txt -Encoding unicode` and all variations with no luck.

*With* `dir`/`ls` *I can see the files correct.*

**PC**:

```
PS C:\tmp> $OutputEncoding

IsSingleByte      : True
BodyName          : us-ascii
EncodingName      : US-ASCII
HeaderName        : us-ascii
WebName           : us-ascii
WindowsCodePage   : 1252
IsBrowserDisplay  : False
IsBrowserSave     : False
IsMailNewsDisplay : True
IsMailNewsSave    : True
EncoderFallback   : System.Text.EncoderReplacementFallback
DecoderFallback   : System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback
IsReadOnly        : True
CodePage          : 20127

PS C:\tmp> [Console]::OutputEncoding

IsSingleByte      : True
BodyName          : ibm737
EncodingName      : Greek (DOS)
HeaderName        : ibm737
WebName           : ibm737
WindowsCodePage   : 1253
IsBrowserDisplay  : False
IsBrowserSave     : False
IsMailNewsDisplay : False
IsMailNewsSave    : False
EncoderFallback   : System.Text.InternalEncoderBestFitFallback
DecoderFallback   : System.Text.InternalDecoderBestFitFallback
IsReadOnly        : True
CodePage          : 737
```

**Server**:

```
PS C:\sw> $OutputEncoding

IsSingleByte      : True
BodyName          : us-ascii
EncodingName      : US-ASCII
HeaderName        : us-ascii
WebName           : us-ascii
WindowsCodePage   : 1252
IsBrowserDisplay  : False
IsBrowserSave     : False
IsMailNewsDisplay : True
IsMailNewsSave    : True
EncoderFallback   : System.Text.EncoderReplacementFallback
DecoderFallback   : System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback
IsReadOnly        : True
CodePage          : 20127

PS C:\sw> [Console]::OutputEncoding

IsSingleByte      : True
BodyName          : IBM437
EncodingName      : OEM United States
HeaderName        : IBM437
WebName           : IBM437
WindowsCodePage   : 1252
IsBrowserDisplay  : False
IsBrowserSave     : False
IsMailNewsDisplay : False
IsMailNewsSave    : False
EncoderFallback   : System.Text.InternalEncoderBestFitFallback
DecoderFallback   : System.Text.InternalDecoderBestFitFallback
IsReadOnly        : True
CodePage          : 437
```

I have even tried to modify the console encoding with:

```
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("IBM737")
```

..and still no luck (and also **chcp 65001**).

Any advise would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Weird. Which way do you _get "??" or chinese characters or control characters_? Your first `ROBOCOPY …  /UNILOG:myfiles.txt` creates `myfiles.txt` Unicode with `UTF-16 LE` byte order mark for me (no Greek but Czech system i.e. default Latin font/script).

Comment: Hi,
/LOG:myfiles.txt  -->  10\8\כ?אב?באוח???  ד??? ?כמ (ISO 8859-8 from notepad++)
/UNILOG:myfiles.txt  -->  獥㉜㄰尲〱㡜ㅜ㜰瀮晤ऊ††††瑡牴扩उ† (screen ok)
/UNICODE | Out-File myfiles.txt -Encoding utf8  -->  䴠㼿㿠㿧㼠㼿㼠㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㼿㿧㼿㼿搮捯ऊ††

..etc

Can you tell me the version of robocopy you have to check something?

Comment: `/UNILOG:myfiles.txt --> 獥㉜㄰尲〱㡜ㅜ㜰瀮晤ऊ††††瑡牴扩उ†` gives me a bit senseful text snippet `es\2012\10\8\107.pdf attrib` using `type myfiles.txt` or using `powershell -c $x='';Get-Content "myfiles.txt" -encoding byte ^| ForEach-Object {$x+=[char]$_};$x` from an open `cmd` window under both `chcp 852` or `chcp 1250`; maybe you would try it under Greek code pages `chcp 737` or `chcp 1253`. Then, force right encoding for opening in notepad++. My `robocopy` is, by ResourceHacker, `"ProductVersion", "6.3.9600.17415"` windows 8.1 64bit English.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.
I tried all variables: def - "??‰?†? ‡ M??…?‡?"
chcp 737 - "??? ??? ?????? ??"
chcp 1253 - "??a ??e?a? ci a?aii??? a?."

But I did find a workaround. My version on the server 2008 R2 is XP027 (5, 1, 10, 1027). I read somewhere that the XP026 (5, 1, 2600, 26) worked ok and the truth is that it works as it should "αγορά ψηφιακής φωτογραφικής"!
I have also tried running newer version 10.x (windows 10) but it fails the OS check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My version of robocopy on the server 2008 R2 is XP027 (5, 1, 10, 1027). I read somewhere that the XP026 (5, 1, 2600, 26) worked ok and the truth is that it works as it should!

> *Version XP026: included in Microsoft Robocopy GUI*

I have also tried running newer version 10.x (windows 10) but it fails the OS check.